# Consuming Java JAX-WS WebService provider in Oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap, apache-tomee

I have a following scenario:

1. Oracle Web Service consumer procedure
2. Web Service gateway implemented using JAX-WS (runs in TomEE 1.7.2)
3. External Web Service

External web service is secured using HTTPS, but for testing purposes also has an unsecured version.

(1) and (2) interact over http
(2) and (3) interact over https
and for testing purposes (2) and (3) can be set to use http.

(1) consumes http version without any problem, but when we switch to secured channel, oracle (**utl_http.get_response** method) complains about http protocol error. SoapUI doesnt have any problems, reads soap response.

Here is the HTTP Response headers in SoapUI:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri
Date: 27 Nov 2015 05:31:38 GMT
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I am guessing the problem is in duplicate "Transfer-Encoding" header, as it might get appended to the first like "chucked, chunked" and oracle might not be smart enough :D to parse it.

Anyone has experienced this kind of a problem? Any suggestions?
Run in comments if you want more details to be able to help. 
Thanks in advance!